# How can I fix this python dependency?

Tags: python, greenplum

I just downloaded greenplum for os x. When I try to start the db, I get this error -- which I take to mean that it is missing gppylib.

```
/usr/local/greenplum$ bin/gpstart
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/gpstart", line 9, in <module>
    from gppylib.mainUtils import *
ImportError: No module named gppylib.mainUtils
```

Here is the line from the file that is causing the error:

```
from gppylib.mainUtils import *
```

I try `pip install gppylib` and `pip install gppylib.mainUtils` but neither can find the package. I can't find the package on google.

Am I correctly understanding that python is looking for a package called gppylib? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: Where does this code come from? Maybe there is a hint where to find the required dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
source $GPHOME/greenplum_path.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error, it seems the path isn't set to include `/usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.2.4/lib/python/gppylib/mainUtils.py`, which is where the package is in my installation. When I did `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.2.4/lib/python/` I got another error message:

```
Error: unable to import module: dlopen(/usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.2.4/lib/python/pygresql/_pg.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.2.4/lib/python/pygresql/_pg.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I suspect this is because the pygresql is compiled for a 32 bit architecture, whereas I'm using x86_64 (unrelated to your issue of not finding the gppylib in the first place):

```
$ lipo -info /usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.2.4/lib/python/pygresql/_pg.so
Non-fat file: /usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.2.4/lib/python/pygresql/_pg.so is architecture: i386
```

Note also that the readme says:

> ---
>
> REQUIRED OS SYSTEM SETTINGS FOR GREENPLUM DATABASE
>
> ---
>
> These must be set on all Greenplum hosts (master and segments).  Make
>   sure you restart your system after adding or changing kernel
>   parameters.
>
> Add all of the following to /etc/sysctl.conf:
>
> kern.sysv.shmmax=2147483648
>
> kern.sysv.shmmin=1
>
> kern.sysv.shmmni=64
>
> kern.sysv.shmseg=16
>
> kern.sysv.shmall=524288
>
> kern.maxfiles=65535
>
> kern.maxfilesperproc=65535
>
> net.inet.tcp.msl=60
>
> If using DHCP, add the following line to /etc/hostconfig:
>
> HOSTNAME=""
>
> You would then use this host name when exchanging ssh keys and  when
>   initializing your Greenplum Database system.
>
> ---
>
> POST INSTALLATION STEPS
>
> ---
>
> These are the high-level steps to configure and initialize a new 
>   Greenplum Database instance. For detailed instructions, please  see
>   the 'Greenplum Database Installation Guide' available for download
>   from http://powerlink.emc.com
>
> 1. Allocate a 'gpadmin' OS user to own and run your installation.
>      This user must exist on all Greenplum hosts.
> 2. Source the greenplum_path.sh file in your 'gpadmin' user
>      profile (.bashrc) of your master host. This sets the
>      environment variables needed by Greenplum Database.
> 3. Use the gpseginstall utility to install and configure the
>      Greenplum software on all hosts.
> 4. Create your data directory locations on all Greenplum hosts.
> 5. Use the gpinitsystem utility on the master host to
>      initialize and start your Greenplum Database system. This
>      utility requires a configuration file and a host file.
>      For example:
>
>    gpinitsystem -c gpinitsystem_config -h hostfile_gpinitsystem
>
>    A sample multi-node initialization configuration file can
>      be found in $GPHOME/docs/cli_help/gpconfigs/gpinitsystem_config.
>       Edit the example files to reflect your desired Greenplum Database     configuration.
>
> ---
>
> ABOUT YOUR INSTALLATION
>
> ---
>
> The Greenplum Database installer installs the following files and 
>   directories:
>
> - greenplum_path.sh - Greenplum Database environment variables.
> - GPDB-LICENSE.txt - Greenplum license agreement.
> - LICENSE.thirdparty - Licenses for third-party tools
> - bin - Greenplum Database server programs, client programs, and 
>         management tools.
> - demo - Greenplum Database demonstration programs.
> - docs - Greenplum Database documentation.
> - etc - Sample configuration file for OpenSSL.
> - ext - Bundled programs (such as Python) used by some 
>         Greenplum Database utilies.
> - include - Greenplum Database and PostgreSQL header files.
> - lib - Greenplum Database and PostgreSQL library files.
> - sbin - Supporting/Internal scripts and programs.
> - share - PostgreSQL sample files and templates.
>
> ---
>
> GREENPLUM DATABASE DOCUMENTATION
>
> ---
>
> The following documentation is available for download from
>   http://powerlink.emc.com:
>
> (All Greenplum Database Installations)
>
> - GPDB--README.pdf - Release notes for this version of    Greenplum Database
> - GPInstallGuide.pdf - Greenplum Database Installation Guide
> - GPAdminGuide.pdf - Greenplum Database Administrator Guide
> - GPPerfmonAdminGuide.pdf - Greenplum Performance Monitor Administrator    Guide